# How to use .rstrip() to remove a new line character from a files content

Tags: python

I have a file which contains a short DNA sequence and I want to open the file and then output a sentence which tells you what the dna sequence is and the length of the dna sequence. When I wrote my line of code however it printed the information on two different lines instead of as a sentence on one line.

The code below is what I tried:

```
#Open and read the file containing the dna sequence
file = open("dnaseq.txt")
dna = file.read()

#calculate the length of the dna sequence
dna_length = len(dna)

#print the sequence and the length of the sequence
print("sequence is " + dna + "the length of the sequence is " + str(dna_length))
```

The output from the code above gave me:
sequence is ATCGGATCA
and length is 9

So I then tried the following;

```
#use rstrip to remove the new line character
dna = file.read().rstrip("\n")
```

however this gave me the following:
sequence is   and length is 9

what i want is a code that will give the following output:
sequence is ATCGGATCA and length is 9

Comment: Did you tried `file.read().rstrip()` ? That would remove any newline / empty characters

Comment: How is the accepted answer different from what you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is it ok

```
# Open and read the file containing the DNA sequence
with open("dnaseq.txt") as file:
    dna = file.read().rstrip("\n")  # Read the file and remove the newline character

# Calculate the length of the DNA sequence
dna_length = len(dna)

# Print the sequence and the length of the sequence in a single line
print("sequence is " + dna + " and length is " + str(dna_length))
```